# HTTP REQUEST in curl

Tags: php, http, curl, request

how can I make an HTTP REQUEST in curl with json?

I need to put this in curl for php:

```
POST /api/ra/v1/ping HTTP/1.0
Host: app.kigo.net
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
Content-Type: application/json
{
"PING" : "PONG"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

This is what I've tried, but it shows "Invalid Content-Type header.":

```
<?php
$url = 'https://app.kigo.net/api/ra/v1/ping';
$headers = array( 'Authorization' => 'Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "PING=PONG");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r( $result );
?>
```

Comment: Please provide your attempt.

Comment: There is a lot of examples over the internet. Just do some search, try something and come back if you have some issue.

Comment: Felippe, I've been doing research all day, still cant figure it out

Comment: `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` needs to be an array of header strings, not the key-value pairs you have.

Comment: @JonStirling Could you please give me an example? Because where else could i leave the authorization?

Comment: @Casper See the [documentation](http://php.net/curl_setopt) and search for `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Comment: @JonStirling I see what you mean, but where do I leave the autherization credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` array must be in the form  `array('Header1: value1', 'Header2: value2')` and not `array('Header1' => 'value1', 'Header2' => 'value2')`, see examples in http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Also, if you post JSON data, you should probably `json_encode()` the data you are sending.

```
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$postData = json_encode(array(
    'PING' => 'PONG'
));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://app.kigo.net/api/ra/v1/ping');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```